# NSFetchedResultsController Not Responding to update

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` in one of my `UITableView` and it manages the display of data. The main entity has a number or relationships and when the data in either of those relationships updates, the tableview updates. My problem is this:
If I change data in a relationship like this, everything updates correctly:

```
mainEntity.relationship.name = @"Random new name";
```

But if I change data in a relationship of a relationship, the `NSFetchedResultsController` does not recieve that update:

```
mainEntity.relationship.relationship2.relationship3.name = @"New Random Name";
```

does not send the update to the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate.

Is there something that I need to do to ensure that the delegate receives the updates if a relationship of a relationship's data changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreCode,

Fetch requests are tied to a single entity. The updates are tied to that entity. This is why Core Data sometimes requires denormalized data, i.e. a custom entity that is just used for your table view. You may wish to consider making a special purpose entity.

Andrew